# Copying to row above in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

Is there any way we can quick copy all the row to the above ones:

[image: Excel]

For example I want the blue highlighted row to be filled with content from the row below without manually copy pasting the whole file.

Appreciate your help!

Thank you.

Ctr+D is used for the vice versa case, but it still needs to be done one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the "go to special" function:

[image]

I'm afraid that my excel is in spanish. I still believe it may help.

The steps are:

1. In the first cell in blank use a simple formula like "=D2" to imitate the cell below
2. Copy this cell with the formula
3. Select in the column the range that contains all the cells that you want to fill
4. Use the "go to special" and select "blanks":
   [image]
5. You should have all the target cells selected. ALl you need now is paste just once

Hope it is what you were looking for.
Best regards